# Focus a window under the mouse and send a hotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, automation, autohotkey, hotkeys

When pressing "Ctrl + WheelUp/Down" with the pointer under Chrome I would like to focus the Chrome window once and then send the ^+tab hotkey as shown in my code:

```
Ctrl & WheelUp::
MouseGetPos,,, WinUMID
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %WinUMID%

if (InStr(class,"Chrome_WidgetWin_1")) {
send, {Ctrl down}{Shift down}{tab}
send, {Ctrl up}{Shift up}
}

if not (InStr(class,"Chrome_WidgetWin_1")) {
    IfWinNotActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
}
return

Ctrl & WheelDown::
MouseGetPos,,, WinUMID
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %WinUMID%

if (InStr(class,"Chrome_WidgetWin_1")) {
send, {Ctrl down}{tab}
send, {Ctrl up}
}

if not (InStr(class,"Chrome_WidgetWin_1")) {
    IfWinNotActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
}
return
```

I wouldn't want this window to focus every time I execute "Ctrl + WheelUp/Down" because it slows down the tab switching, since I execute the ^+tab code many times while moving the mouse wheel in one direction ↑↓.

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

Comment #1: If the code is the same for both events, you can use the same code for both combos like this:

```
Ctrl & WheelUp::
Ctrl & WheelDown::

    MouseGetPos,,, WinUMID
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %WinUMID%

    if (InStr(class,"Chrome_WidgetWin_1")) {
        send, {Ctrl down}{tab}
        send, {Ctrl up}
    }

    if not (InStr(class,"Chrome_WidgetWin_1")) {
        IfWinNotActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
            WinActivate, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
    }

return
```

Comment #2: You didn't really ask a question, but I would guess from the post that A) the code works but B) it fires off events too fast or too often, which causes a problem with the window focus(?)

If that is the case, you could try using a variable to track A_TickCount and simply return if there has not been a long enough delay between function calls for the wheelup/down events...

```
if (A_TickCount<(lastTick+500)) ; this event is <500ms from last event?
&& (A_ThisHotkey=lastHotkey)    ; scroll direction still the same?
    return

lastTick := A_TickCount
lastHotkey := A_ThisHotkey
```

Also, if you ever moved this type of code into a function eventually, you would need to declare the 'last' variables as static, in order to retain their values in between function calls.